# Static attributes (Python vs Java)

Tags: java, python, class, attributes

What is the difference between Python class attributes and Java static attributes?

For example,

in Python

```
class Example:
    attribute = 3
```

in Java

```
public class Example {

    private static int attribute;

}
```

In Python, a static attribute can be accessed using a reference to an instance?

Comment: Python class attributes can be accessed via the class itself _or_ through an instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, you can have a class variable and an instance variable of the same name [[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/758280)]:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     i = 3
...
>>> MyClass.i
3 

>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.i = 4
>>> MyClass.i, m.i
>>> (3, 4)
```

In Java, you cannot have a static and non-static field with the same name (the following will *not* compile, you get the error "Duplicate field MyClass.i"):

```
public class MyClass {
  private static int i;
  private int i;
}
```

additionally, if you try to assign a static field from an instance, it will change the static field:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static int i = 3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    m.i = 4;

    System.out.println(MyClass.i + ", " + m.i);
  }
}
```

> 4, 4

---

In both Java and Python you can access a static variable from an instance, but you don't need to:

Python:

```
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.i
3
>>> MyClass.i
3
```

Java:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new MyClass().i);
    System.out.println(MyClass.i);
  }
```

> 3
>   3